# Thread::Join vs detach

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Why should I using `std::thread::join` and then wait until this thread has ended? I thougt the purpose of multithreading is, that I start more threads paralelly. 
Instead of `join()`, I also could call the function "normally", like `foo()`.
So why is their `join()`? Isn't the only thing I need `detach()`?

Comment: You can do stuff between the start of the thread and the call to `join`, which will then be executed concurrently. `thread::join` makes sure the thread is done by the time that call returns, so you can, for example, safely use the result.

Comment: `join` and `detach` are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @BaummitAugen what do you mean with start of the thread? The initialization?

Comment: @RoQuOTriX Yes. Initialization with some function that is, a default constructed thread does nothing.

Comment: Classic use case: a program that uses multiple threads to do one large computation, and then it stops.  Main thread spawns workers, and maybe does a share of the work itself.  Then it join()s all of the workers, combines their results, prints the report, and exits.  But it's important not to try combining the results until the workers have all finished.

Comment: Join basically means. Wait here until this thread ends. Threads will not BLOCK your code, this means, if you need the value from the thread somewhere the only way to ensure that the result of the thread is correct is waiting for the thread to end. That is why we have join, to ensure that the thread finished at that point.

Answer (score 5):

Consider what happens here:

```
int value = 0;
void myWorkerFunction(){value = 1;}

int main()
{
   std::thread t(myWorkerFunction);
   t.detach();
   std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

You now have a race condition. Your thread may or may not complete all the work it needs to do before `value` needs to get printed.<sup>*</sup>

Consider `join` to be a form of synchronization like a `mutex`; you must wait for the executing thread to release the mutex (finish) before you can continue.

Sometimes it makes sense to detach a thread, if say, it can just "work in the background" performing tasks that may not be mission critical.

> I thougt the purpose of multithreading is, that I start more threads paralelly [sic]

You are not forced to `join` a thread immediately after it is created. You can create N threads, and then go off and do some other work. Only when you want to guarantee that a thread has finished do you need to `join`.

---

<sup>*</sup>This example is way oversimplified for the sake of explanation. Often thread creation happens in some other object or function outside of `main`. Whether to detach or not is usually pretty obvious from your design. (however we must always `detach` or `join` a `std::thread` before it goes out of scope)